# Have to Click Button Twice to Perform Function - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, user-interface

For some reason I have to press the button twice to perform the function that it is assigned to, maybe something to do with the fact that there are two click events? However, if I remove the "$(buttonNumber).on('click', function ()" the script breaks. 
I plan to use this function for multiple buttons and that's why it has to be in a function.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="test2.js"></script>

    </head>

 <body>

<button id="button1" onclick="nextSlide('#button1', '#1', '#2')">Hide it</button>
<p id="1">Hide this text</p>
<p id="2">Show this text</p>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
window.onload=function(){
    $('#2').fadeOut(1);

};

function nextSlide(buttonNumber, hideDiv, showDiv) {
    $(buttonNumber).on('click', function () {
            $(hideDiv).hide("slide", 2000, function(){
                $(showDiv).show("slide", 2000);
            });
    });
};
```

Comment: why do you include both v1 and v2 of jquery? this is not necessary. remove one and see if your problem persists.

Comment: One of them is the jQuery UI libary required for the slide function.

Comment: ;-) now that you mention it… :P sry 4 the noise!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are binding the event on every click. You should just execute the code within your click event.

```
function nextSlide(buttonNumber, hideDiv, showDiv) {
    //$(buttonNumber).on('click', function () {
            $(hideDiv).hide("slide", 2000, function(){
                $(showDiv).show("slide", 2000);
            });
    //});
};
```

The commented parts binds a click event, but you have already done this in your html:

```
onclick="nextSlide('#button1', '#1', '#2')"
```

Comment: A better answer would be to do this without the inline binding.